# Sending arguments to ftw()

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

Is there a way to send arguments to ftw() to be used in process each file/directory on the path? It's a bit difficult to have the argument concerned as a global variable due to multithreading issues, i.e having the value as global will be visible to all threads and that would be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

A properly designed C callback interface has a `void*` argument that you can use to pass arbitrary data from the surrounding code into the callback.  `[n]ftw` does not have such an argument, so you're kinda up a creek.

If your compiler supports thread-local variables (the `__thread` storage specifier) you can use them instead of globals; this will *work* but is not really that much tidier than globals.

If your C library has the `fts` family of functions, use those instead.  They are available on most modern Unixes (including Linux, OSX, and recent *BSD) and [gnulib has a fallback implementation](http://www.gnu.org/s/gnulib/MODULES.html#module=fts).

Comment: `__thread` is nonstandard and not portable, but you could instead use `pthread_key_create` and `pthread_setspecific`/`pthread_getspecific`.